# How to put a kendo-grid inside another kendo-grid such that both the grids are editable on-cell click?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have 2 components - trial1(parent kendo-grid), trial2(child kendo-grid). Inside trial1's template i referenced sub-grid component trial2. But I get an error where trial2 isn't recognised inside trial1.

```
<ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
  <button kendoGridAddCommand type="button" class="btn btn--secondary btn--small addTableRow"><span class="icon-add"></span></button>
  <button *ngIf="formGroup" (click)="cancelHandler()" class="k-button k-primary">Cancel</button>
</ng-template>

<kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let details of dTable.columns;let i = index;" [field]="details.field" [title]="details.title" width="details.width" [editable]="true">
</kendo-grid-column>

<ng-template kendoGridDetailTemplate let-dataItem>

    <trial2></trial2>

  </ng-template>

<kendo-grid-command-column title="command" width="100">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-isNew="isNew">
        <button kendoGridRemoveCommand class="label label--circle label--small btn btn--secondary show icon-presence-end">X</button>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-command-column>

</kendo-grid>
```

Solutions in Angular (not JQuery) would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the [master-detail grid demo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/advanced-features/hierarchy/)
To set up [in-cell editing](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/in-cell-editing/#toc-basic-concepts) you need to add following events on both master and detail grid components:-

- cellClick -> Display input on click of cell
- cellClose -> Save data on leaving cell

```
//Master component
@Component({
    providers: [CategoriesService],
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <kendo-grid
          [data]="view | async"
          [loading]="view.loading"
          [pageSize]="pageSize"
          [skip]="skip"
          [sortable]="true"
          [sort]="sort"
          [pageable]="true"
          [height]="550"
          [navigable]="true"
          (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
          (cellClick)="cellClickHandler($event)"
          (cellClose)="cellCloseHandler($event)"
        >
        <kendo-grid-column field="CategoryID" width="100"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="CategoryName" width="200" title="Category Name"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="Description" [sortable]="false">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <div *kendoGridDetailTemplate="let dataItem">
            <category-details [category]="dataItem"></category-details>
        </div>
      </kendo-grid>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    public view: Observable<GridDataResult>;
    public sort: Array<SortDescriptor> = [];
    public pageSize = 10;
    public skip = 0;

    @ViewChild(GridComponent) grid: GridComponent;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private service: CategoriesService) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        // Bind directly to the service as it is a Subject
        this.view = this.service;

        // Fetch the data with the initial state
        this.loadData();
    }

    public dataStateChange({ skip, take, sort }: DataStateChangeEvent): void {
        // Save the current state of the Grid component
        this.skip = skip;
        this.pageSize = take;
        this.sort = sort;

        // Reload the data with the new state
        this.loadData();
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // Expand the first row initially
        this.grid.expandRow(0);
    }

    private loadData(): void {
        this.service.query({ skip: this.skip, take: this.pageSize, sort: this.sort });
    }

    public cellClickHandler({ sender, rowIndex, columnIndex, dataItem, isEdited }) {
        if (!isEdited) {
          console.log(sender);
            sender.editCell(rowIndex, columnIndex, this.createFormGroup(dataItem));
        }
    }

    public cellCloseHandler(args: any) {
        const { formGroup, dataItem } = args;

        if (!formGroup.valid) {
             // prevent closing the edited cell if there are invalid values.
            args.preventDefault();
        } else if (formGroup.dirty) {
            console.log("save data")
        }
    }

    public createFormGroup(dataItem: any): FormGroup {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            'CategoryID': dataItem.CategoryID,
            'CategoryName': [dataItem.CategoryName, Validators.required],
            'Description': [dataItem.Description, Validators.required],
        });
    }
}
```

```
//Detail component
@Component({
    selector: 'category-details',
    providers: [ProductsService],
    template: `
      <kendo-grid
          [data]="view | async"
          [loading]="view.loading"
          [pageSize]="5"
          [skip]="skip"
          [pageable]="true"
          [scrollable]="'none'"
          (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"

          [navigable]="true"
          kendoGridFocusable
          (cellClick)="cellClickDetailsHandler($event)"
          (cellClose)="cellCloseDetailsHandler($event)"
        >
      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="Product ID" width="120">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" format="{0:c}">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      </kendo-grid>
  `
})
export class CategoryDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    /**
     * The category for which details are displayed
     */
    @Input() public category: Object;

    public view: Observable<GridDataResult>;
    public skip = 0;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private service: ProductsService) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.view = this.service;

        /*load products for the given category*/
        this.service.queryForCategory(this.category, { skip: this.skip, take: 5 });
    }

    public pageChange({ skip, take }: PageChangeEvent): void {
        this.skip = skip;
        this.service.queryForCategory(this.category, { skip, take });
    }

     public cellClickDetailsHandler({ sender, rowIndex, columnIndex, dataItem, isEdited }) {
        if (!isEdited) {
          console.log(sender);
            sender.editCell(rowIndex, columnIndex, this.createFormGroupDetail(dataItem));
        }
    }

    public cellCloseDetailsHandler(args: any) {
        const { formGroup, dataItem } = args;

        if (!formGroup.valid) {
             // prevent closing the edited cell if there are invalid values.
            args.preventDefault();
        } else if (formGroup.dirty) {
            console.log("save data")
        }
    }

    public createFormGroupDetail(dataItem: any): FormGroup {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            'ProductID': dataItem.ProductID,
            'ProductName': [dataItem.ProductName, Validators.required],
            'UnitPrice': dataItem.UnitPrice,
            'UnitsInStock': [dataItem.UnitsInStock, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{1,3}')])],
            'Discontinued': dataItem.Discontinued
        });
    }
}
```